# Use css to style instead of jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have encountered this code :

```
$("#customTable tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("newColour");
```

This colours every odd row of the table.

How can this be handled within css instead of using jQuery to perform it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#customTable tr:nth-child(odd) { 
    background-color:#eee; 
}
#customTable tr:nth-child(even) { 
    background-color:#fff; 
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/m45hr/)**

Comment: Same note as in the other answer, the selector is incomplete.

Comment: @Tadeck Question may be different,but answer should be one only.

Comment: @j08691: You received downvote when your answer was still incomplete. This is what's with the downvote.

Comment: @prash: please clarify "_Question may be different,but answer should be one only._". What answer? The question was clear, this answer was incomplete, now it should be sufficient.

Comment: sorry i thought you downwoted because of the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#TABLE_ID tr:nth-child(odd) {YOUR RULE HERE}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 #customTable  tr:nth-child(even) {background: color;}
   #customTable tr:nth-child(odd) {background: color;}
```

This links may help you

http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html